# How to implement autocomplete textfield in iphone using threading

Tags: iphone, multithreading, autocomplete, textfield

I have one url which i have to hit every time whenever user enters single character in textfield.Everytime the feeds changes and i have to store those result in an array and show it in autocomplete textfield . Right now i am doing this without threading and it becomes too slow to fetch data from feed.I know it has to be implemented with threading if anyone know how to do this please post your view.

Comment: Showing your existing code would help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to worry about threading.  `NSURLConnection` has methods for performing the request asynchronously.  You just give it a delegate or a completion block and it will call you when the request is complete.